# Position element inside pseudo element

Tags: html, css

I would like to add a fontAwesome inside the circle's `:after` pseudo element. When I try to add a `content:`, it appears on the top left of the pseudo element. When I try to move it, all the circle and the content move.

I would like the `?` or any other icon from fontAwesome to be in the middle. By the way, how can I add a fontawesome directly in CSS?

```css
.le_quiz_entier {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: 45px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px #40c8d6;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.le_quiz_entier .post-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 2%;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #404040;
}

.le_quiz_entier .postbody {
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.le_quiz_entier .postbody a:visited {
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 22px;
  color:#404040;
}
.le_quiz_entier .cta {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#38C8D6;
}
.le_quiz_entier .cta:visited {
  color:#38C8D6;
}

.le_quiz_entier:before, .le_quiz_entier:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  top: 0;
}

.le_quiz_entier:before {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 5px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.le_quiz_entier:after {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    z-index: 1;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(#41c9d7, 0.56);

    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.le_quiz_entier::after {
  content:"?";
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="le_quiz_entier"></div>
```

Comment: This is because the pseudo element is being positioned relative to its parent! Why don't you simply add another element? If you don't want to add another element use margin!

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just like any element, to center the text, use `text-align: center;`, and to put the text in the middle vertically, set `line-height` to the same height of the container:

```
.le_quiz_entier::after {
  content:"?";
  margin-top: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

Here is the entire code:

```css
.le_quiz_entier {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: 45px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px #40c8d6;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.le_quiz_entier .post-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 2%;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #404040;
}

.le_quiz_entier .postbody {
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.le_quiz_entier .postbody a:visited {
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 22px;
  color:#404040;
}
.le_quiz_entier .cta {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#38C8D6;
}
.le_quiz_entier .cta:visited {
  color:#38C8D6;
}

.le_quiz_entier:before, .le_quiz_entier:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  top: 0;
}

.le_quiz_entier:before {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 5px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.le_quiz_entier:after {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    z-index: 1;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(#41c9d7, 0.56);

    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.le_quiz_entier::after {
  content:"?";
  margin-top: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="le_quiz_entier"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update css properties

```
.le_quiz_entier::after {
  content:"?";
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```css
.le_quiz_entier {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: 45px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px #40c8d6;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.le_quiz_entier .post-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 2%;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #404040;
}

.le_quiz_entier .postbody {
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.le_quiz_entier .postbody a:visited {
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 22px;
  color:#404040;
}
.le_quiz_entier .cta {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#38C8D6;
}
.le_quiz_entier .cta:visited {
  color:#38C8D6;
}

.le_quiz_entier:before, .le_quiz_entier:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  top: 0;
}

.le_quiz_entier:before {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 5px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.le_quiz_entier:after {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    z-index: 1;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(#41c9d7, 0.56);

    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

                 /* Update css properties*/

.le_quiz_entier::after {
  content:"?";
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="le_quiz_entier"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.le_quiz_entier {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: 45px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px #40c8d6;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.le_quiz_entier .post-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 2%;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #404040;
}

.le_quiz_entier .postbody {
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.le_quiz_entier .postbody a:visited {
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 22px;
  color:#404040;
}
.le_quiz_entier .cta {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#38C8D6;
}
.le_quiz_entier .cta:visited {
  color:#38C8D6;
}

.le_quiz_entier:before, .le_quiz_entier:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  top: 0;
}

.le_quiz_entier:before {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 5px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.le_quiz_entier:after {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    z-index: 1;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(#41c9d7, 0.56);

    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.le_quiz_entier::after {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 50px; /* the same as the :after height */
    content:"?";
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="le_quiz_entier"></div>
```

Comment: Always add an explanation to your answers so the OP and others learn why/how your answer works. Also avoid adding an answer that is identical to an already existing one. Your answer is identical to mine, so what is the benefit of repeating my answer here? Perhaps you didn't copy my answer, but you need to take a look at the existing answers before you answer a question, so you don't repeat them.